# Nestjs: How to build nestjs app and generate dist folder?

Tags: node.js, nestjs

I am trying to write jenkins shell script to deploy nestjs app,
I try "npm run start:prod" this generate dist folder, but it serve also the app which I dont need it,

How to just build the app ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can run:

`npm run build`

This will just build application. This script can be found in generated Nest.js project when you generate project with Nest CLI.

The script itself could look like this:

`"build": "tsc -p tsconfig.build.json"`

And content of `tsconfig.build.json` could look like this:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "test", "**/*spec.ts"]
}
```

Comment: I dont have build script in package.json, can you write it here ?

Answer (score 1):

Add the following command in the `script` tag in the **package.json**

```
 "scripts": {
    "build": "nest build"
    ...
  },
```

then run :

```
npm run build
```

or you can run the following command in the terminal:

```
npx tsc -p tsconfig.build.json
```