# NestJS: How to build and deploy the nestJS app only with javascript

Tags: javascript, nestjs, nestjs-config

I've implemented a NestJS app in Javascript without the TS support. And I would like to deploy it. I'm wondering how one can achieve that. All the documentation points to how to do that using typescript. Using a `nest build` command, mentioned here in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57408815/6537332). But there is no proper documentation for achieving this with Javascript. There is also an issue [here](https://github.com/nestjs/javascript-starter/issues/20) without the proper answer.

Here are the current scripts in my project

```
"scripts": {
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.js\"",
    "start": "babel-node index.js",
    "start:dev": "nodemon",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json"
  },
```

I believe I should not be using babel in production env. I should be building the app files and use  `node dist/main`. But how can I build the app?

Answer (score 0):

You'll still need babel-node in production, because babel is what allows you to make use of the decorators that are a non-standard feature in node. So long as you move your `src/`,`index.js`,`package.json` and lock-file, install production dependencies on your server, then you should be able to just `babel-node index.js` and have it working